# Divide one column in array by another numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to get

```
[[ 4.    0.   0. ]
 [ 8.    0.  0.  ]]
```

out of this:

```
[[ 2.    0.5   0.  ]
 [ 2.    0.25  0.  ]]
```

So I want to divide the first column by the second one:

`div = arr[:,0]/arr[:,1]` but don't know what's the best way to reshape and add zeros to get the result.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do it in place, you could do

```
a[:, 0] = a[:, 0] / a[:, 1]
a[:, 1] = 0
```

If not

```
b = np.zeros(6).reshape(2, 3)
b[:, 0] = (a[:, 0] / a[:, 1])
```